# Where can I find the gpg key for dotdeb.org

Tags: debian, apt, dotdeb, keys

Who knows where the gpg key for dotdeb.org repository (for debian lamp packages) can be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dotdeb repositories just (July 11th, 2010) [got GPG-signed](http://www.dotdeb.org/2010/07/11/dotdeb-packages-are-now-signed/):

> After many requests from several users and after many months of promise, the Dotdeb repositories are GPG-signed. Yes, you can now get rid of the annoying “*WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!*” message!
>
> Waiting for a dotdeb-keyring package, you just have to get [the appropriate file](http://packages.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg) by hand and add it to your trusted keys’ keyring :
>
> ```
> gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 89DF5277
> gpg -a --export 89DF5277 | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> I hope you’ll enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

Accord to this: http://www.dotdeb.org/2009/03/11/php-529-is-packaged-at-last/#comment-1332 the packages in that repo are not GPG signed so there is no key. Considering that comment is 6 months old now I could be wrong but I can't find anything to the contrary.